# Parsing bbcode quotes with variable attributes in PHP

Tags: php, bbcode

I've been trying my best to avoid coming here and asking this, insisting to myself that I could solve it on my own. I have done that, but I thought i'd come here anyway to 1) share my solution or 2) get a better solution.

I know there are already a ton of stackoverflow questions on this, most say use the PEAR library and none are about my specific question.

Basically I want to be able to parse the bbcode quote tag, however this quote can have a variable number of attributes or no attributes at all so a simple preg_replace won't work in the same way as it would for say an underline tag.

There can also be multiple quote tags within one string, here's an example of how I solved it. Can anyone suggest a better way avoiding the multiple regex expressions and foreach loops?

(it should be noted i'm parsing the strong tag in the example, but I am doing this elsewhere in my code, its the quotes i'm specifically struggling with and asking about here)

```
$string = "[quote name='Rob' user_id='1' id='1' timestamp='1294120376']
My text here
[/quote]

[quote name='Rob' user_id='1' id='2' timestamp='1302442553']
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
[/quote]

Test Comment";

preg_match_all('/\[quote(.*?)](.*?)\[\/quote\]/msi', $string, $matches);

$quotes = array();

foreach($matches[1] as $id => $match)
{
    preg_match_all('/(\w*?)=\'(.*?)\'/msi', $match, $attr_matches);

    array_push($quotes, array(
        'text'          =>  trim($matches[2][$id]),
        'attributes'    =>  array_combine($attr_matches[1], $attr_matches[2])
    ));
}

echo '<pre>'.print_r($quotes,1).'</pre>';
```

This will output the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [text] => My text here
            [attributes] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Rob
                    [user_id] => 1
                    [id] => 1
                    [timestamp] => 1294120376
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [text] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
            [attributes] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Rob
                    [user_id] => 1
                    [id] => 2
                    [timestamp] => 1302442553
                )

        )

)
```

Then I simply build the HTML

```
$bbcode = '';

foreach($quotes as $quote)
{
    $attributes = array();
    foreach($quote['attributes'] as $key => $value)
    {
        switch($key)
        {
            case 'id':
                $attributes[] = '<a href="'.site_url('forums/findpost/'.$value).'">Permalink</a>';
            break;
            case 'name':
                if(isset($quote['attributes']['user_id']))
                {
                    $attributes[] = 'By <a href="'.site_url('user/profile/'.$quote['attributes']['user_id'].'/'.$value).'">'.$value.'</a>';
                }
                else
                {
                    $attributes[] = 'By '.$value;
                }
            break;
            case 'timestamp':
                $attributes[] = 'On '.date('d F Y - H:i A', $value);
            break;
        }
    }

    if(!empty($attributes))
    {
        $bbcode .= '<p class="citation">'.implode(' | ', $attributes).'</p>';
    }


    $bbcode .= '<blockquote>
        '.$quote['text'].'
    </blockquote>';
}

echo $bbcode;
```

Which will output the following:

```
<p class="citation">By <a href="http://domain.com/user/profile/1/Rob.html">Rob</a> | <a href="http://domain.com/forums/findpost/1.html">Permalink</a> | On 04 January 2011 - 05:52 AM</p>
<blockquote>
    My text here
</blockquote>

<p class="citation">By <a href="http://domain.com/user/profile/1/Rob.html">Rob</a> | <a href="http://domain.com/forums/findpost/2.html">Permalink</a> | On 10 April 2011 - 14:35 PM</p>
<blockquote>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</blockquote>
```

So this seems like a very long and round about way of doing it but I can't fathom another method. Anyone...?

Comment: It fails when you get input like this: `[quote ...] foo [quote ...] bar [/quote] foo [/quote]`

Comment: For my purposes quotes within quotes could never happen, but a simple solution would be to put it in a function and call it recursively.

Comment: Okay. But you can't simply call it recursively (at least, not without changing your regex). You'd replace `[quote ...] foo [quote ...] bar [/quote]` and leave a `[/quote]` dangling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to come up with my own more elegant solution that is both less code and will work with nested quotes.

This will only parse the quotes, the content within and around the quotes will still need to be converted from bbcode, but there are plenty of resources available for that.

```
function parse_quote($matches) {
    $bbcode = '';
    preg_match_all('/(\w*?)=\'(.*?)\'/msi', $matches[1], $attr_matches);
    $attributes = array_combine($attr_matches[1], $attr_matches[2]);
    if(!empty($attributes))
    {
        $attribute_strings = array();
        foreach($attributes as $key => $value)
        {
            switch($key)
            {
                case 'id':
                    $attribute_strings[] = '<a href="http://domain.com/forums/findpost/'.$value.'">Permalink</a>';
                break;
                case 'name':
                    if(isset($quote['attributes']['user_id']))
                    {
                        $attribute_strings[] = 'By <a href="http://domain.com/user/profile/'.$attributes['user_id'].'/'.$value.'">'.$value.'</a>';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $attribute_strings[] = 'By '.$value;
                    }
                break;
                case 'timestamp':
                    $attribute_strings[] = 'On '.date('d F Y - H:i A', $value);
                break;
            }
        }


        {
            $citation = '<p class="citation">'.implode(' | ', $attribute_strings).'</p>'."\n";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $citation = '';
    }

    return $citation.'<blockquote>';
}

$string = "[quote name='Rob' user_id='1' id='1' timestamp='1294120376']
[quote name='Rob' user_id='1' id='2' timestamp='1302442553']
[quote name='Rob' user_id='1' id='3' timestamp='1302442553']
Test at a comment of a third depth
[/quote]
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
[/quote]
This is my comment
[/quote]

[b]Test Comment[/b]";

$new_string = str_replace('[/quote]', '</blockquote>', $string);
echo preg_replace_callback('/\[quote(.*?)\]/msi','parse_quote', $new_string);
```

This should return the following

```
    <p class="citation">By Rob | <a href="http://domain.comforums/findpost/1">Permalink</a> | On 04 January 2011 - 05:52 AM</p>
<blockquote>
<p class="citation">By Rob | <a href="http://domain.comforums/findpost/2">Permalink</a> | On 10 April 2011 - 14:35 PM</p>
<blockquote>
<p class="citation">By Rob | <a href="http://domain.comforums/findpost/3">Permalink</a> | On 10 April 2011 - 14:35 PM</p>

<blockquote>
Test at a comment of a third depth
</blockquote>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</blockquote>
This is my comment
</blockquote>

Test Comment
```

Answer (score 0):

> So this seems like a very long and round about way of doing it but I can't fathom another method.

For using *regexes* to work with BBCode, it's actually pretty sane... though you seem to have discarded `[b]Test Comment[/b]` at the end.

As alluded to in the comments, this method is going to break the instant your tags become nestable.  [I've previously written about that problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371536/php-how-do-i-remove-nested-tags-and-relocate-them-in-an-un-nested-way/5372002#5372002), and pretty much the only sane solution is going to be building a "real" parser to deal with that insanity.  I have yet to encounter an existing third-party BBCode parser that does this correctly.

However, as you don't believe nesting is an issue, this code should work well enough.  Don't forget to filter the attributes in the tags for unfriendly characters.  If `site_url` doesn't do so, then you've created an XSS vulnerability.

Comment: Thanks for the link it lead me to some other places, i've edited the question with a new solution that's less code and works with nested quotes. I decided the best idea was to replace the beginning and end of quotes seperately and not worry about what's inbetween.

Comment: As long as you don't need to actually process any of the text in between the tags and can trust the user to remember to close their opens, that solution should work out pretty well for you.

Comment: I do need to process the data inbetween the tags but that can happen elsewhere with relative ease (e.g. strong and underline tags). But quotes are complicated enough to require separating so now what I can do is parse the entire user input which will deal with everything inside and outside the quotes and then  deal with just the quotes.

Comment: Sorry to ask but what is the etiquette for answering my own question, your response was useful so i'd be happy to accept it as the answer or should I leave it as is?

Comment: If you don't feel that any of the answers posted helped you, it's perfectly acceptable to actually post a new answer to your own question, detailing the changes you made that solved your issue.   FYI for others that might be reading, [a recent change](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange) means that newish users will now need to wait a day before posting a self-answer.