# BBCode - Regex match only none or both quotes on attributes

Tags: php, regex, bbcode

I'm trying to build a regex that will match BBCode attributes. I want it to match attributes without quotation marks (`attr=value`) and also with them (`attr="value"`), but don't match if there's only one mark (`attr="value` or `attr=value"`).

I managed to get close to a solution with this regex `/\[size\=((?=")"(.*?)"|([^"]*))\](.*?)\[\/size\]/is` (for size tags), using a lookahead, but it places the match for the quoted and unquoted attributes on different indexes. Here's a scheme:

```
+-----------------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| Input                 | Match #1 | Match #2 | Match #3 | Match #4 |
+-----------------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| [size="7"]txt[/size]  | "7"      | 7        |          | txt      |
+-----------------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| [size=7]txt[/size]    | 7        |          | 7        | txt      |
+-----------------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

While this is not a major issue, I'd like to know if there's any wya to match them to the same index.

**Background Info:**

Basically, I'm working on improving a BBCode parser. As for now, it only allows attributes to be placed without quotation marks `"`. Now, that brings a whole lot of limitations to it, so I'm adding support to quoted attributes. Problem is I can't break backwards compatibility, so I gotta come up with something that works for both cases.

Comment: @JonahBishop, problem with stripping is that it brings some of the limitations it originally had for not supporting it quoted. If any of the attribute's values had, for instance, an equal sign `=`, the parser would think it's a new attribute instead.

Comment: Consider using something other than regexes.  [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5372002/168868).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the group which matches your first case must be distinct from the group matching the second case, I don't believe there's any way to get them to match to same index/group.

It's not unusual to see code working around this like the following though:

```
attr = matches[1] or matches[2]
```

Since you can know for sure that at most 1 of those elements are non-empty, the `or` logic works.

Comment: That was kinda how I got it to work, but since I was doing replacement straight on the result string, instead of `ORing` them, I simply concatenated it. Forgot to reply with my solution.