# nbbc code parser - disable all bbcodes inside code tag

Tags: php, parsing, bbcode

I'm using nbbc parser for bbcode tags.

I only want to ignore all tags code inside [code] and [/code] elements.

The demo is here : http://nbbc.sourceforge.net/full_example.php

And the home page is here : http://nbbc.sourceforge.net

You can try usibg :

```
[code]
test
[code]
test
[/code]
[/code]
```

I read the documentation but doesen't say nothing about this :(

Comment: by ignoring you mean....? give an example.

Comment: I expect that what's happening is that NBBC is regex-based and is in non-greedy mode.  That means that the first open code is being matched to the first closed code, meaning the stuff between the first close and second close isn't being included.  Alternatively, it's greedy and loop based, meaning that the things inside the inner code tag are being incorrectly transformed twice.  I guess I'm going to have to stop recommending it.  [BBCode is harder than you think](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5372002/168868).